# Using for and if commands for a list of strings in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am making a batch file for windows. I have just started learning batch scripting and I have some problems here.

```
@echo off
set langList=("eng","fre","chi")

:Get_ISOlanguage
set "ISOlanguage="
set /p ISOlanguage=Enter subtitle language in ISO 639-2 standard abbreviation:
set ISOlanguage="%ISOlanguage%"

for %%x in %langList% do (
if ""%ISOlanguage%"" == ""%%x"" (echo LANGUAGE SUPPORTED
goto :CONTINUE))
echo LANGUAGE NOT SUPPORTED 
goto :GET_ISOlanguage

:CONTINUE
echo ayy lmao

pause
```

Instead of

`for %%x in %langList% do (if ""%ISOlanguage%"" == ""%%x"" (echo LANGUAGE SUPPORTED&goto :CONTINUE))`

If the user types e.g `eng` how can I get e.g `Your chosen language is English` and then continue the batch? If the user enters something that is not in the langList I want to display an error message saying "wrong input, please Try again".

Comment: You need to start with the answer to your previous question (which shows you how to use correctly use`for` to check for a valid entry). And have a separate list (`nameList`) with the language names in it to output the real name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I read somewhere you want to keep the list inside your batchfile instead of a data file. Most obvious solution for this would be to define a lot of variables, but I prefer another method:

```
@echo off
:Get_ISOlanguage
set "language=not supported"
set /p "ISOlanguage=Enter language code: "
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%i in ('find "DATA,%ISOlanguage%," "%~f0"') do set language=%%i
echo language is %language%
if "%language%"=="not supported" goto :Get_ISOlanguage


goto :eof
DATA,eng,English
DATA,fre,French
DATA,chi,Chinese
DATA,ger,German
DATA,deu,German
DATA,chn,Chinook jargon
```

Comment: @Arete did a complete rework.