# windows cmd /c enters interactive mode

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, cmd.exe, make

A friend of mine has a Windows 10 system that shows the following behavior:

When GNU make is used to run a command using "cmd /c" and the command string contains a wildcard character, then the invoked cmd.exe does not terminate (as documented for the /c option) but stays in interactive mode.

Example makefile:

```
clean:
        @echo makefile: making clean
        -cmd /c del /s *.pyc
        @echo makefile: made clean
```

Invoking make:

```
(prompt) > make clean
makefile: making clean
cmd /c del /s *.pyc
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
(prompt) >
```

When entering `exit`, the makefile continues:

```
makefile: made clean
```

So obviously the `cmd /c ...` invokes the command processor in interactive mode.

When the asterisk is removed, that does not happen:

Example makefile:

```
clean:
        @echo makefile: making clean
        -cmd /c del /s x.pyc
        @echo makefile: made clean
```

Invoking make:

```
(prompt) > make clean
makefile: making clean
cmd /c del /s x.pyc
The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile: made clean
(prompt) >
```

This happens exactly when an asterisk is in the command line, or when double quotes are used (as in `cmd /c "del /s x.pyc"`).

I have never seen such a behavior before, and i don't have Windows 10 to try it out myself.

Does anyone know why it enters the command processor in interactive mode?

Comment: Try adding /q to your command. `del /q /s *.pyc`

Comment: See also this question on a related but different topic: https://superuser.com/questions/1037133/using-for-and-if-commands-for-a-list-of-strings-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Appleoddity: The actual del command was using /q /f, I simplified it somewhat.